# Multiprocessing using cuda

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pytorch, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run multiprocessing in my python program. I created two processes and passed a neural network in the one process and some heavy computational function in the other. I wanted the neural net to run on GPU and the other function on CPU and thereby I defined neural net using cuda() method.

```py
import cv2
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import multiprocessing as mp    #I even tried import torch.multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import set_start_method
try:
    set_start_method('spawn')
except RunTimeError:
    pass

class network(nn.Module):
    '''neural net class'''

def func1(img, net):
    '''used to call neural net'''

def func2(img):
    '''image processing part'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    net = network().cuda() #here network is my neural net class
    img = cv2.imread('img.png')
    p1 mp.Process(target= func1, args=(img, net))    #func1 is used to run neural net
    p2 = mp.Process(target=func2, args=(img,))    #func2 is used for some img-processing
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

But when I run the program the got the following error:
**RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the ‘spawn’ start method**

So I tried with **spawn** as well as **forkserver** start method, but then I got the other error:
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (71) : operation not supported at …/torch/csrc/generic/StorageSharing.cpp:245

I have tried python3 multiprocessing and torch.multiprocessing both but nothing worked for me.

Comment: don't do this at the start of main: `net = network().cuda() #here network is my neural net class` do it in one of your created processes.    You don't want anything cuda-related in your main before you create your processes.  So that may include your OpenCV call depending on how your OpenCV is built.

Comment: I have initiated the 'net' object in 'func1()' instead of creating it in main() and then passing it to the function. Though it worked but the creation of object is taking a lot of time hence the idea of using multiprocess for saving time is not served!

Answer (score 1):

put `set_start_method` inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`

the code will be

```
import cv2
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import multiprocessing as mp    #I even tried import torch.multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import set_start_method


class network(nn.Module):
    '''neural net class'''

def func1(img, net):
    '''used to call neural net'''

def func2(img):
    '''image processing part'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    set_start_method('spawn')
    net = network().cuda() #here network is my neural net class
    img = cv2.imread('img.png')
    p1 mp.Process(target= func1, args=(img, net))    #func1 is used to run neural net
    p2 = mp.Process(target=func2, args=(img,))    #func2 is used for some img-processing
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```